# What types are valid for the `self` parameter of a method?

Tags: methods, syntax, rust

I wanted to create a method that only works where the `self` parameter was an `Rc`. I saw that I could use `Box`, so I thought I might try to mimic how that works:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    fn consuming(self) {}
    fn reference(&self) {}
    fn mutable_reference(&mut self) {}
    fn boxed(self: Box<Bar>) {}
    fn ref_count(self: Rc<Bar>) {}
    fn atomic_ref_count(self: Arc<Bar>) {}
}

fn main() {}
```

Yields these errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched method receiver
  --> a.rs:11:18
   |
11 |     fn ref_count(self: Rc<Bar>) {}
   |                  ^^^^ expected struct `Bar`, found struct `std::rc::Rc`
   |
   = note: expected type `Bar`
   = note:    found type `std::rc::Rc<Bar>`

error[E0308]: mismatched method receiver
  --> a.rs:12:25
   |
12 |     fn atomic_ref_count(self: Arc<Bar>) {}
   |                         ^^^^ expected struct `Bar`, found struct `std::sync::Arc`
   |
   = note: expected type `Bar`
   = note:    found type `std::sync::Arc<Bar>`
```

This is with Rust 1.15.1.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Before Rust 1.33, there are only four valid method receivers:

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn by_val(self: Foo) {} // a.k.a. by_val(self)
    fn by_ref(self: &Foo) {} // a.k.a. by_ref(&self)
    fn by_mut_ref(self: &mut Foo) {} // a.k.a. by_mut_ref(&mut self)
    fn by_box(self: Box<Foo>) {} // no short form
}

fn main() {}
```

[Originally](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/14022), Rust didn't have this explicit `self` form, only `self`, `&self`, `&mut self` and `~self` (the old name for `Box`). This changed so that only by-value and by-references have the short-hand built-in syntax, since they are the common cases, and have very key language properties, while all smart pointers (including `Box`) require the explicit form.

As of Rust 1.33, [some additional selected types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/56805) are available for use as `self`:

- `Rc`
- `Arc`
- `Pin`

This means that the original example now works:

```
use std::{rc::Rc, sync::Arc};

struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    fn consuming(self)                  { println!("self") }
    fn reference(&self)                 { println!("&self") }
    fn mut_reference(&mut self)         { println!("&mut self") }
    fn boxed(self: Box<Bar>)            { println!("Box") }
    fn ref_count(self: Rc<Bar>)         { println!("Rc") }
    fn atomic_ref_count(self: Arc<Bar>) { println!("Arc") }
}

fn main() {
    Bar.consuming();
    Bar.reference();
    Bar.mut_reference();
    Box::new(Bar).boxed();
    Rc::new(Bar).ref_count();
    Arc::new(Bar).atomic_ref_count();
}
```

However, the `impl` handling hasn't yet been fully generalised to match the syntax, so user-created types still don't work. Progress on this is being made under the feature flag `arbitrary_self_types` and discussion is taking place in [the tracking issue 44874](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44874).

(Something to look forward to!)

Comment: So I can reasonably expect that other library types besides `Box` will be supported at some point in the future?

Comment: Yes, supporting other pointer types is the major motivation for the change in syntax.

Comment: Returning to this many months later; any changes you know of in this area? The code as-is fails to compile, so nothing obvious yet.

Comment: @Shepmaster see my answer below.

Comment: Maybe interesting to note that in addition to e.g. Arc<T>, self can also be &Arc<T> or &mut Arc<T>. Probably most use cases would prefer just &T, but maybe some methods would like to clone the Arc that T is sitting in.

Comment: @huon please add a link to https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#methods which documents all of the currently supported variants

Comment: I just needed a &Arc<Self>, and I'm glad it was there! The method used to receive a &self, but this simple change enables me to Arc::clone() it and send it into a tokio::spawn...

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to use arbitrary types for `self`, including `Arc<Self>`, but the feature is considered unstable and thus requires adding this [crate attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454761/what-is-a-crate-attribute-and-where-do-i-add-it):

```
#![feature(arbitrary_self_types)]
```

Using `feature` crate attributes requires using nightly Rust.

Comment: I would add that despite the name, arbitrary self types aren't quite "arbitrary", but must (transitively) deref to `Self`. So `self: Arc<Self>` and `self: &Arc<Self>` are fine, but `self: Vec<Self>` isn't. (Of course the details are subject to change before stabilization.)

Comment: This answer is outdated now.