# What is a crate attribute and where do I add it?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In order to get a feel for how Rust works, I decided to look at a little terminal-based text editor called [Iota](https://github.com/gchp/iota). I cloned the repository and ran `cargo build` only to be told:

> ```
> error: *if let* syntax is experimental
>
> help: add #![feature(if_let)] to the crate attributes to enable
> ```

Where am I supposed to add `#![feature(if_let)]` to the crate attributes?

Comment: As a side-note, newer (nightly) builds of Rust have enabled this feature by default, so updating Rust will also remove your problem.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

A crate attribute is an attribute (`#[...]`) that applies to the enclosing context (`#![...]`). This attribute must be added to the top of your *crate root*, thus the context is the crate itself:

```
#![attribute_name]
#![attribute_name(arg1, ...)]
```

If you are creating

- a library — the crate root will be a file called `lib.rs`
- an application — the crate root would be the primary `.rs` file you build. In many cases, this will be called `main.rs`
- an integration test - the crate root is each file in `tests/`
- an example - the crate root is each file in `examples/`

---

[*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html#non-operator-symbols) and the [Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) talk a bit about attributes in general. [The Unstable Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/) contains a list of feature flags and brief documentation on what they do.

There are many different crate attributes, but the `feature` crate attribute (`#![feature(feature1, feature2)]`) may only be used in a **nightly** version of the compiler. Unstable features are not allowed to be used in stable Rust versions.

Comment: Why #![...] is called Inner attributes? in the substrate project, there is a line  on top of file `#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]`  what is this line means? does it have some relation to the declaration in the Cargo.toml file in which usually  a definition like `[features]
default = ['std']`

Comment: @gfan because it's an attribute _inside_ of the thing it's applied to. See also https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/intro/no-std.html