# How to fix `definition of unknown language item 'panic_fmt'`?

Tags: rust, panic

For a `no_std` application there are a few language items defined in `lang_items.rs`, one of them being the `panic_fmt` language item (to specify the behavior of `panic!` in this `no_std` context) defined like:

```
#[lang = "panic_fmt"] #[no_mangle] pub extern fn panic_fmt() -> ! { loop{} }
```

When compiling, I receive this error:

```
error[E0522]: definition of an unknown language item: `panic_fmt`
 --> src/lang_items.rs:3:1
  |
3 | #[lang = "panic_fmt"] #[no_mangle] pub extern fn panic_fmt() -> ! { loop{} }
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ definition of unknown language item `panic_fmt`

error: `#[panic_implementation]` function required, but not found
```

After reading [RFC 2070](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2070-panic-implementation.html) I learned there was a recent breaking change for `no_std`/embedded programs. While it's recommended that I use the `#[panic_implementation]` attributes, a recently added feature, I still receive an error, doing so like:

```
#[panic_implementation] #[no_mangle] pub extern fn panic_fmt() -> ! { loop{} }
```

Gives the error:

```
error[E0658]: #[panic_implementation] is an unstable feature (see issue #44489)
 --> src/lang_items.rs:4:1
  |
4 | #[panic_implementation] #[no_mangle] pub extern fn panic_fmt() -> ! { loop{} }
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: add #![feature(panic_implementation)] to the crate attributes to enable
```

Following their suggestion of adding `#![feature(panic_implementation)]` to the top of the `lang_items.rs` file doesn't seem to do the trick, as I'm getting the same error. How do I enable this unstable feature properly so that I can compile this `no_std` application with behavior for `panic!` defined?

Comment: What is "lang_items.rs"? That's nothing standard.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Do you know that `feature`s require a nightly compiler?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a nightly compiler :-).

Comment: *Following their suggestion of adding `#![feature(panic_implementation)]` to the top of the lang_items.rs file* — that is **not** the suggestion. Possible duplicate of [What is a crate attribute and where do I add it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27454761/155423).

Comment: Thanks shepmaster, I read your answer earlier and then realized what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it was a simple mistake I was making. Here is a link to the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=aefd00397e89920ea72dffa6dc99fb93&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015) containing my code. First of all, I needed to add the crate attribute to the *top* of my crate root (which, for me, was `lib.rs`). `lang_items.rs` was just a file that was used in `lib.rs` like so:

```
#![feature(compiler_builtins_lib, lang_items, asm, panic_implementation, core_intrinsics)]
#![no_builtins]
#![no_std]

pub mod lang_items;

const GPIO_BASE: usize = 0x3F000000 + 0x200000;

const GPIO_FSEL1: *mut u32 = (GPIO_BASE + 0x04) as *mut u32;
const GPIO_SET0: *mut u32 = (GPIO_BASE + 0x1C) as *mut u32;
const GPIO_CLR0: *mut u32 = (GPIO_BASE + 0x28) as *mut u32;

#[inline(never)]
fn spin_sleep_ms(ms: usize) {
    for _ in 0..(ms * 600) {
        unsafe { asm!("nop" :::: "volatile"); }
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn kmain() {
    // STEP 1: Set GPIO Pin 16 as output.
    GPIO_FSEL1.write_volatile(0x1 << 0x12);
    // STEP 2: Continuously set and clear GPIO 16.
    loop {
        GPIO_SET0.write_volatile(0x1 << 0x10);
        spin_sleep_ms(256);
        GPIO_CLR0.write_volatile(0x1 << 0x10);
        spin_sleep_ms(256);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to duplicate answers when an existing Q&A has already solved the problem. That just increases the amount of maintenance needed to keep Q&A useful.