# How do I assert that a Rust futures-preview future has not yet resolved

Tags: rust

I'm trying to bring my dependencies up-to-date. I have some code that uses futures-preview and futures-timer. Earlier versions of futures-timer included the ability to put a timeout on a future, and I have a test that uses this feature, but it was [removed](https://github.com/async-rs/futures-timer/commit/f3d1d77cf6e9c7c84a7f128913676e7cf2ae16ef) from recent releases.

Is there a straightforward way of just checking to see if the future has resolved and then fail the test if it has? (Also, is "resolved" the correct word?)

I tried playing around with `f1.poll()` but couldn't quite figure out the return type and how to work with it.

I also tried using the [timeout from async_std](https://docs.rs/async-std/0.99.9/async_std/future/fn.timeout.html) but I got a bunch of errors along these lines:

```
error[E0008]: cannot bind by-move into a pattern guard
   --> /Users/nathan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-std-0.99.9/src/net/driver/mod.rs:207:17
    |
207 |             Err(err) if err.kind() == io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {}
    |                 ^^^ moves value into pattern guard
    |
    = help: add `#![feature(bind_by_move_pattern_guards)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

Unless I'm mistaken, that's asking me to modify async-std, right? Is there a way around that?

Here's my test:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use crate::threadpool::ThreadPool;
    use futures_timer::TryFutureExt;

    // ....

    #[test]
    fn test_trigger_future_untriggered() {
        let tf = TriggerFuture::default();
        let f1 = tf.future();

        ThreadPool::default()
            .spawn_wait::<_, _, ()>(async {
                f1.map(|_| Result::<(), std::io::Error>::Ok(()))
                    .timeout(std::time::Duration::from_millis(50))
                    .await
                    .expect_err("expected timeout");
                Ok(())
            })
            .expect("expected!");
    }
}
```

Update: Here's one more thing I tried. With futures-timer v1.0.1, it fails as expected if I uncomment the `tf.trigger()`, but it runs forever when I don't. What's wrong here?

```
    #[test]
    fn test_trigger_future_untriggered() {
        let tf = TriggerFuture::default();
        let f1 = tf.future();

        // tf.trigger();

        ThreadPool::default()
            .spawn_wait::<_, _, _>(async {
                use futures_timer::Delay;
                let delay = Delay::new(std::time::Duration::from_millis(50));
                future::select(f1, delay).then(|either| {
                    match either {
                        Either::Left((_, b)) => b.map(move |y| (Err("this future shoudn't resolve"), y)).left_future(),
                        Either::Right((_, a)) => a.map(move |x| (Ok("expected timeout"), x)).right_future(),
                    }
                }).await.0
            })
            .expect("expected!");
    }
```

Here is my Cargo.toml as requested:

```
[package]
name = "shared_futures"
version = "0.1.0"
publish = false
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
futures-preview = { version = "0.3.0-alpha.19", features = [ "async-await", "compat" ] }
crossbeam-channel = "0.3.9"
num_cpus = "1.10.1"
# Note: the timeout feature was removed in futures-timer v0.6
futures-timer = "1.0.1"

[features]
sanitizer_safe = []

[lib]
name = "shared_futures"
crate-type = ["rlib"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out (with a little help). My final attempt was close but was doing too much. This is a simplified version that actually works:

```
    #[test]
    fn test_trigger_future_untriggered() {
        let tf = TriggerFuture::default();
        let f1 = tf.future();

        tf.trigger();

        ThreadPool::default()
            .spawn_wait::<_, _, &str>(async {
                use futures_timer::Delay;
                let delay = Delay::new(std::time::Duration::from_millis(50));
                let res = future::select(f1, delay).await;
                match res {
                    Either::Left(..) => Err("The TriggerFuture resolved first"),
                    Either::Right(..) => Ok(()),
                }
            })
            .expect("The Delay should have resolved first");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you kindly post your Cargo.toml and any use statements that belong to the example code? I can't run your code but after looking over your test example and error message I believe there are some [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454761/what-is-a-crate-attribute-and-where-do-i-add-it) (and here) that may help you.

Can you try updating to the latest version of nightly and see if it fixes the issue? It appears the feature was [recently stabilized](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/63118).

```
rustup update nightly
```

This is assuming you are using the nightly version of the rust compiler.

Best of luck.

Comment: Posted the Cargo.toml. I had looked at your linked question already, but I don't think it answer the issue I was having. 
I'm on a nightly from about 4 days before that stabilization merge, but it's locked in to keep the team all on the same version. 
However, I figured out the issue with my last variation and posted an answer below that works without needing any additional libraries (or a newer rust version).

Comment: Terrific that you solved the issue.  Wish I could have been of more help!