# Disable a warning for a whole file?

Tags: rust

I have been struggling define aliases for primitive types.

```rust
#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]

pub type i32x2 = [ i32 ; 2 ]; 
pub type f64x2 = [ f64 ; 2 ];
pub type f64x4 = [ f64 ; 4 ];
```

Is there a way to disable a warning for a whole file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. And you were pretty close to it

```
#![allow(non_camel_case_types)] // at the top of the file
```

It can also be used at the top of your `lib.rs` file to disable those warnings for all the files in your library.

The way you would do it if it is not just for prototyping:

```rust
#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
mod types {
    pub type i32x2 = [i32; 2];
    pub type f64x2 = [f64; 2];
    pub type f64x4 = [f64; 4];
}
```

See also:

- [What is a crate attribute and where do I add it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454761/what-is-a-crate-attribute-and-where-do-i-add-it)

Comment: Be careful, as this answer disables the warning for the **whole crate**, not just one file

Comment: No @AlexeyLarionov it disables it in the file you use it in and its sub modules.