# Box type and method syntax in Rust

Tags: rust

Why does this code work?

```
trait T: std::fmt::Debug {
    fn func(mut self: Box<Self>) -> Box<T>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    i: i32,
}

impl T for S {

    fn func(mut self: Box<Self>) -> Box<T> {
        self.as_mut().i += 1;
        self
    }
}

impl S {
    fn new() -> Box<S> {
        Box::new(S{i: 0})
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S::new();
    let s_inc = s.func();
    print!("{:?}", s_inc);
}
```

(Playground)

In particular, I don't understand how the type annotation `mut self: Box<Self>` in

```
impl T for S {
    fn func(mut self: Box<Self>) -> Box<T> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

works. Shouldn't `self` be of type `S`, not `Box<S>?` Which part of the method rules allow for this syntax?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25462935/155423 ?

Comment: Not exactly the same question but that response answers my question. Apparently `Box<Self>` is a valid type for `self`, which wasn't made clear in the rust-book.