# Multiple iterations of vector with structs "cannot move out of borrowed content"

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I need to iterate a vector with structs in each iteration in a loop. It works fine as long as the vector doesn't contain structs. I have tried many different solutions but always get some kind of ownership problem.

What am I doing wrong?

```
struct Element {
    title: String,
}

impl Element {
    pub fn get_title(self) -> String {
        self.title
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut items: Vec<Element> = Vec::new();
    items.push(Element {
        title: "Random".to_string(),
    });
    items.push(Element {
        title: "Gregor".to_string(),
    });

    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 10 {
        for item in &items {
            println!("Loop {} item {}", i, item.get_title());
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b4ea87a8a44bdc853b06358db1efe16a)

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:23:44
   |
23 |             println!("Loop {} item {}", i, item.get_title());
   |                                            ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Comment: I advice you to read the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/)

Comment: Thanks I have read the book 3 times, I can't understand how you can think this is duplicate question. The other question accesses same variable in two dimensional loop, my question doesn't

Comment: "The other question accesses same variable in two dimensional loop, my question doesn't" that doesn't change anything. The point of the duplication is that if you iter so you borrow the value you can't use function that consume the value.

Comment: Note that you can drastically [simplify your example by manually unrolling the loop](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cd22d9c91a0a5a46c33c089800822b3e). Once you've made it as simple as possible, it's more apparent why it's a duplicate. You'll also want to use [`vec!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html) in your real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that your `get_title` method consumes the `Element` and therefore can only be called once.
You have to accept `&self` as parameter instead and can do the following:

Either return a `&str` instead of `String`:

```
pub fn get_title(&self) -> &str {
    &self.title
}
```

or clone the `String` if you really want to return a `String` struct.

```
pub fn get_title(&self) -> String {
    self.title.clone()
}
```

Also have a look at these questions for further clarification:

- [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)
- [What types are valid for the `self` parameter of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462935/what-types-are-valid-for-the-self-parameter-of-a-method)

Comment: @cjohansson Because you tried to edit my code you also should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o

Comment: Thanks ok, my edit worked but it wasn't best practice, didn't know about that

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a solution to the problem**, it required *borrowing self object* and *lifetime specifications*.

Moving from `&String` to `&str` is only for following better practices, thanks @hellow [Playground 2](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4333c268c0d239391cb07e5640710af4)

```
struct Element<'a> {
    title: &'a str
}

impl <'a>Element<'a> {
    pub fn get_title(&self) -> &'a str {
        &self.title
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut items: Vec<Element> = Vec::new();
    items.push(Element { title: "Random" });
    items.push(Element { title: "Gregor" });

    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 10 {
        for item in &items {
            println!("Loop {} item {}", i, item.get_title());
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now you made your struct hold references. Why? You overshot the target.

Comment: This is just a hypothetical example, I have a more advanced example I'm working on were it makes sense